# How to read images from a file containing individual paths to the images

Tags: python, image, csv

I want to read Images into python. These Images are contained in different Folders. there is a csv file containing the full path of every Image. I would like to use cv2.imread() to get the Images. How can I do that?

Comment: please provide an [MCVE]

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with a csv file named "testcsv.csv" and storing one path(with extension) by line you can do:

```
import csv
import cv2
with open("testcsv.csv") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        img = cv2.imread(row[0])
```